# Android Retrieve data from EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am new to android programming, so please be forgiving. This is my first app, its purpose is to find strings typed in the search widget by the user in txt placed on sd card. I almost finished it, but my last goal was to add a feature that would allow the user to decide how many answers he wants to get after searching. So I added an EditText field where i can type a number. And that is my problem: I can't retrieve data that I typed in EditText field, and I don't know why. This is my onCreate.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_a_number); // I think this is the firs part of my problem...

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        int number = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()); // ...and that is the second
        do_my_search(query, number);
    }
}
```

and do_my_search method:

```
   public void do_my_search(String query, int number) {
      //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"fragment.txt");

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "windows-1250"),8192);
        String line;
        String[] text = new String[5];
        int i = 0;
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) == true && i < number){
                text[i] = i + 1 + "." + line + "\n";
                i++;
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < number ; i ++){
            if(text[i] == null)
                text[i] = "";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String value : text) {
            builder.append(value);
        }
        String final_string = builder.toString();
        Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(final_string);
        for(i = 0;; ){
            int k = final_string.indexOf(query,i);
            if (k == -1)
                break;
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), k, k + query.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            i = k + query.length();
        }

        textView1.setText(wordtoSpan);
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
}
```

Everything but the text field works fine. I have browsed some similiar threads and I think my problem is that the variable number gets the value before I type anything in the field, it always picks the default text, even if it is showing something different. I know that probably there will be some errors in my code, but right now I'm interested in solving this particular issue: what should I do to make my variable number pick the value that i type in my edittext field? And is it possible without adding buttons or TextWatcher?

Comment: Can you post your activity_main.xml file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pDtjmHqk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a listener to your `EditText`, in order to retrieve its value once changed.

Your "first problem" should not be an actual problem (retrieving the `EditText` by id as a child `View` of the main `Layout`), as long as the `EditText` is declared in your main `Layout` xml, and has that id assigned.

The simplest way to solve your issue is to declare a `String` variable as instance property of your main `Activity`. Let's call it `theText` and assign it an empty `String`.

Note that you don't really need an instance variable, you might want to use the value of the text change directly - it really boils down to whether you need to re-use that after processing it with your search method or not. In the example below, I assume you have an instance `String` variable `theText` declared and assigned in your `Activity`.

Add the listener to your `EditText` as such:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // we assign "theText" a value here
        theText = s.toString();
        // we test it here (assuming your main Activity is called "MainActivity"
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, theText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // you can do whatever with the value here directly (like call "do_search"), 
        // or launch a background Thread to do it from here
    }
});
```

Now once the text has been changed by the user, the value of `theText` will be updated to that text and you can use it elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I cant find where you get the text entered.... to receive text from the edittext you need

```
String myText=edittext.getText().toString()
```

well actually you just need `edittext.getText().toString()` but you get the point... i trust you know where to put it once you get it.

and then use it to whatever purpose you want...
then you can also get it as an int with `Integer.parseInt(myText)` if you need a Int from the string.

Answer (score 1):

From this line,

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_a_number);
```

You just got a view, EditText view. Now you need to get the data, user has entered. To do this, use the following line after that

```
 String eText=editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `edittext.getText().toString()` to get data from EditText. It returns a string which you can store in a string variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
EditText edtemail;
String email;
```

... then inside the oncreate method

```
edtemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_email);
email=edtemail.getText.toString();
```